# Can I mix top-level domain with subdomain applications on Heroku using "Custom Domains" add-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, subdomain

According to heroku, http://addons.heroku.com/custom_domains
"The wildcard domain add-on enables you to use *.yourdomain.com. You can have as many wildcard domains as you like on one app."

Let say i have a domain call abc.com
can i use abc.com for 1st rails app, another.abc.com for 2nd rails app, another2.abc.com for 3nd rails app? this 3 rails is separate/different heroku rails app? i would like to know cause heroku say "as many wildcard domains as you like on one app."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. You can condense your apps basically into 1 (if even necessary), and follow the guide here

http://www.railsdev.ws/blog/10/using-subdomains-in-rails-apps/

to learn how to route based on subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 separate applications on Heroku as you describe then you just need a single custom domain per application (ie not the wildcard addon). If you use the wildcard domain addon to add say *.mydomain.com then you will not be able to use the same domain (mydomain.com) for any subsequent applications you host on Heroku.